# Can i make my own version of YAGO2s?

Tags: windows, version, wikipedia, entities

I am familiar with Stanford Core NLP and NER. I know how to make my own version of entities and how to use it.

But with YAGO2s im a bit confused.
I'd like to know, is there a way to make my own knowledgebase like [YAGO2s](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/), using Wikipedia, WordNet and GeoNames or other encyclopedias?

If there is, how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds rather outdated. :)

Use Wikidata's own approach: [install Wikibase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation) for MediaWiki, import a Wikidata dump, start playing with it.